# Is it possible to make attachments mandatory when creating custom github issue templates?

Tags: github, templates, yaml, github-issues

I want to create a custom template in GitHub for issues where i can make attachments mandatory. So when someone in my organization uses my issue template, they have to add an attachment before opening the issue.
How is this possible in GitHub?

I read already that u can create custom issue templates with YAML, but nothing about how to make attachments mandatory.